# How do you activate touch for mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, touch

I'm sorry but I can't find decent instructions on how to do this. I have  links on a responsive site, and I want them to activate touch on them all on mobile devices. What is the best/easiest way to do so? Apparently there is away and it speeds up reaction time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

touch is a native function in the OS